# Does this double integral require u substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$\int_0^1\int_0^3 e^{x+3y}$$dxdy$

$3y$ is treated like a constant so I am really just dealing with x here. How do I go about integrating this?

Comment: $e^{x+3y}=e^xe^{3y}$

Comment: No, the function is separable so you can evaluate both terms independently of one another.

Comment: Okay I see you just used rules of exponents to simplify it

Comment: in the former that integrates to $\frac{1}{3y}e^{3y}$ correct?

Comment: The derivative of $e^{3y}$ is $3e^{3y}$, so $\frac{1}{3}e^{3y}$ is an antiderivative of $e^{3y}$.

Comment: @smcc Since this is multivariate, one should say "The derivative of $e^{3y}$ with respect to $y$ is ..."

Comment: Yes, I thought about editing it before you made your comment, but then I decided it was obvious enough and decided not to.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $$e^{x+3y}=e^{x}e^{3y}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^1\int_0^3 e^{x+3y} dy dx = \int_0^1 e^x dx\int_0^3 e^{3y} dy$

You can can break apart a double integral like this when the limits of integration do not depend on one another.